# Jest --coverage ignores Nest.js controller and service files

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage, nestjs

I have written tests for a Nest.js project for all controller and service files (which are adhering to the usual `myApp.service.ts | myApp.controller.ts` naming convention).

I can successfully run all tests for the files, however, when I attempt to generate a coverage report with `jest --coverage`, controller and service files are omitted (regardless of them being tested or not), while all other files are included, including files following similar naming convention, i.e. `myApp.module.ts`.

### My Jest configuration:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
],
  "rootDir": "src",
  "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
},
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.(t|j)s"
],
  "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

### Things I've tried:

- Removing `*.spec.ts` files.
- Adding exclusion rules to `collectCoverageFrom` to make sure that the config is being loaded (it is).
- Adding new, more specific rules to `collectCoverageFrom`, such as `**/*.service.ts`, `**/*.controller.ts` as well as absolute paths to specific files.
- Adding the same rules to `forceCoverageMatch`

Nothing has worked thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting `node_modlues`, `dist` and `package-lock.json` and reinstalled dependencies with `yarn`. Doing the same with `npm` didn't work.

Still not quite sure what the cause was.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. I solved by [clearing jest cache (`--clearcache`)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--clearcache).

Comment: Deleted: `node_modules`, `coverage`, `build`. Ran: `npm i`, `npx jest --clearCache`, now for whatever reason it seems I'm able to run `npx jest --coverage` without issue 